# how to include footer in php on codeiginter framework

Tags: codeigniter, include

I thought it is an easy task to do, but some errors show up as a result of what I did. I wrote  two simple pages in the **view**; 1- header + body 2- footer.
Then I simply added the following code to the controller's main file:

```
$this->load->view('footer.php');
$this->load->view('main.php');
```

And in the main.php (header+body) I added a php line to include the footer like this:

```
<?php include("footer.php"); ?>
```

however the error is still showing up...

And the error message is this:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: include(footer.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

any idea how to resolve this issue?

All comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is probably because the include in your view should be pointing to the footer.php in your views folder, something like /applications/views/footer.php.

However, including views like that is not the correct way to do it.  In your controller you can output multiple views sequentially, so this should be all you need:

```
$this->load->view('main');
$this->load->view('footer');
```

Notice the lack of an extension, you only need to pass the name of the file.  This will load and render the views one after the other.

Comment: have you removed the `include` line from your main.php view?

Comment: no, it is still there... by the way, do I have to activate the function **include_path** in the php.ini in order to make it work?

Comment: no, you need to remove that include line or set the path to your footer view correctly, that's where the error comes from.

Comment: What if I want to render a file inside a particular div. in that case rendering sequentially won't work. as design is structure dependent.

Answer (score 1):

You have to read the documentation...

Place all of your HTML pages into the /application/views/ directory, then, include them by :

```
$this->load->view('footer');
```

Note that we don't specify the .php file extention.